# Anime where the MC uses water and earth magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can only remember this once scene from an anime where the mc goes to this small town and has water and earth magic and is able to make a bath for everyone and the young (I think) women go into the bath and he catches some nobles or guards or something from another town trying to sneak in and stops them.

I think there was another scene as well where he faces off against one of those same woman’s father and is able to fight evenly with him even though he’s supposed to be a really strong guy.

I’m not sure if it was an isekai or not.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking about [Spirit Chronicles (Seirei_Gensouki)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/44203/Seirei_Gensouki)?

[Episode 7](https://www.bilibili.tv/en/video/2045452247) has this series of events. The main character Rio builds a bath to wash off after a day's hunting, Ruri and Sayo are fascinated and use the bath.

Later, 3 youths from another town bust their wagon to stay in the village, their plan being to sneak in and force themselves on Ruri and Sayo. Rio catches them and inflicts a serious amount of damage to the intruders.

The fight with the father occurs later, with wooden swords, as a test of Rio's combat ability.

Comment: Hi. It'd be great if you could look up the title of the specific episode where these events occurred, and then edit your answer to include it.

Comment: I'll try to remember that in the future @LogicDictates. First post here so I'm not totally sure of the etiquette. Thanks to those who edited my brief answer into a good answer.

Comment: Valorum submitted that edit literally one second after I posted my comment. :-)